# Multiply the first number of each cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset ={ 
         "g1":[(1,2,3), (1,4,5),(6,5,8)],
         "g2":[(6,5,4),(9,6,4),(5,8,7)],
         "g3":[(2,5,6),(6,5,8),(5,8,6)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame (dataset, index = ["g1", "g2", "g3"])
print(df)
```

[image]

This is my dataframe. I want to multiply the first elements of the columns for each row (I marked the numbers I want to multiply with a blue pencil) then I want to print them in the column named R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) to slice and [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html):

```
df['R'] = df.apply(lambda c: c.str[0]).prod(axis=1)
```

Or convert your DataFrame to 3D numpy array:

```
a = np.array(df.to_numpy().tolist())

df['R'] = a[..., 0].prod(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           g1         g2         g3    R
g1  (1, 2, 3)  (6, 5, 4)  (2, 5, 6)   12
g2  (1, 4, 5)  (9, 6, 4)  (6, 5, 8)   54
g3  (6, 5, 8)  (5, 8, 7)  (5, 8, 6)  150
```

Comment: C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6848\946875620.py:1: FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  df['R'] = df.apply(lambda c: c.str[0]).prod(axis=1)

Comment: wrote all R columns as 1.0

Comment: This doesn't happen with the provided example. Please clarify.